# Limiting JTextArea size to the size of its text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea of a fixed size (300 x 33) with line wrapping enabled that I have added inside of a JPanel. Whenever one types inside it and goes past the last visible row (in this case the second one), the text continues outside of the text area's view, and is hidden.

Is there anyway to limit the text entered inside of a JTextArea to the size of the text area rather than to the number of characters that it contains (making it dependent to the different space that each character of different fonts occupies)?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that not fixing the size of the JTextArea and providing row and column numbers in the constructor would result in the text area to stretch and fill the JPanel holding it. I believe this is due to the fact that the panel's layout is a BoxLayout.

Comment: If you limited the text, what would happen if the user tried to add more text? What about if they tried to paste text into the component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't fix the size of a JTextArea. Rather initialize it by calling its constructor with decent column and row number parameters, and put it in a JScrollPane so if the text increases, you'll not lose the text.

Comment: I had original done that, but since the layout of the JPanel containing it was a BoxLayout, the JTextArea would stretch much more than the constraints that I had given.

Comment: @JCtrl: Again the JTextArea would be inside of a JScrollPane, and you could even place this into another JPanel if need be before adding to the BoxLayout-using container.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that your method will be a lot more effective for my application in the long end, though I will have to change some code (not only the JTextArea). Thanks for tip.